# Why aren't my included graphics properly colored?

Tags: graphics, color

When I include graphics in my document, the colors are always converted to grayscale, which is very unfortunate as I depend on the colors in the images.

I use LaTeX => PS => PDF for creating my document. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps,.png,.pdf}
\graphicspath{{E:/.../images/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[bb=0 0 966 503,scale=0.4]{images/highlight}
    \caption{Hervorgehobenes Bauteil}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The following image is the result.

[image]

Comment: Works for me with `latex` + `dvipdfm` and with `pdflatex` (after removing the `bb` option). I have no idea with editor/IDE you use and which commands it executes for LaTeX => PS => PDF. You could try to remove the PNG to EPS manually or simply use `pdflatex` (most likely called LaTeX => PDF for you).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using pdfLaTeX, which directly supports PNG image format. This means directly compiling to PDF, instead of using DVI and PS as intermediate format.

If you also need (E)PS images, you can use the `epstopdf` LaTeX package or the program with the same name and include them as PDF files.

Comment: That worked nicely. I just included `epstopdf`, deleted the `bb`-attributes and everything works. Thanks a bunch!