# JPEG images changed to black and white

Tags: graphics, jpeg

All my jpg images in LaTeX are coming out in black and white. 
Similar question [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13187&p=50074), but it doesn't seem to answer my question. 
I am using Texmaker and latex + dvips + sp2pdf + ViewPDF

Here is an example of my code:

```
 \documentclass[12pt,oneside,openany,a4paper,%..... Layout
           afrikaans, english,%.............. Global language selection
           ]{memoir}
 \usepackage{babel}%.............................. Language setup
\usepackage{graphicx}%........................... Graphicx loaded in usthesis


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,natwidth=831,natheight=812]{FourHeliostatsTry3.jpg}
\caption{Intersection and transformation of four heliostats}
\label{Ffourheliostats}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason for using `latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf` instead of just compiling with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Jake - No. Thanks for reminding me. I had a problem a while back and blindly fiddling with the configuration settings helped. Just forgot to change it back. pdflatex also doesn't work

Comment: Hm, I can't reproduce that. Just to be sure, if you remove the `afrikaans` option, the problem persists? Also, what happens if you call `pdflatex <document>` from a console instead of through your editor?

Comment: I haven't got a high enough rep yet to post images. But I tried a couple of jpegs including ones I pulled form the net. **note** could it be the order of  latex + dvips + sp2pdf + ViewPDF It seems to be the only thing that works. I also use MiKteX 2.9 and Windows 7

Comment: @Seb: What editor are you using? Could you edit your question to include the `.log` file that's produced when you compile the document using `pdflatex`?

Comment: If I try `pdflatex` with the MWE and a JPG of my own [https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10200702207178160&l=248b7fce92] FWIW, I get colour as expected.  If I do `latex -> dvips` the ps is greyscale.  If I do `latex ->dvipdfm` the pdf is in colour - so I suggest avoiding dvi2ps unless you really want ps

Comment: Something similar has been asked before: [Why aren't my included graphics properly colored?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19512/28808) with similar issues around going through .ps, but I can't really believe that LaTeX -> DVI -> ps can't handle colour

Comment: @ChrisH - That seems to sort it out latex->dvipdfm. I have no why idea LaTeX->DVI->PS doesn't work, but apparently it doesn't. Thank for the help!

Comment: @Seb: If the problem only appears with `dvips`, it's very likely that you need to use `dvips -I c <filename>` instead of just `dvips <filename>` (see http://www.win.tue.nl/latex/faq.html#q16). That wouldn't explain why it happens with `pdflatex`, though.